# Docker: Django and Postgresql: What is better two separate containers or one?

Tags: django, docker

I plan to deploy my django app in docker. 
This application uses Postgresql as backend, so I've faced a question, what is better deployment scheme: two docker containers - one for app and one for DB, or one container with everything?

I think separate containers is more scalable, because I can independently change number of app-workerks,  but it's harder to configure DNS naming resolution and maybe it's less secure than one container?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but if possible you should run SELinux on your docker host as it can automatically build SE linux profiles to protect your containers from breaking out into your host. More here: http://opensource.com/business/14/7/docker-security-selinux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend two containers for the exact reason you listed. You can make changes to one container without having to alter the other one. To your security question, there are ways to securely link the containers as well. You can potentially only allow the app container direct network access and only expose the backend container to the app container. There are some more details on linking  here: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/. Let me know if you have any follow up questions.